# Outer merge between pandas and imputing NA with preceeding row

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes containing the same columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'b': [2,3,4,5,6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,3,4],
                    'b': [2,4,5]})
```

I want `df2` to have the same number of rows as `df1`. Any values of `a` not present in `df1` should be copied over, and corresponding values of `b` should be taken from the row before.

In other words, I want `df2` to look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'b': [2,2,4,5,5]})
```

EDIT: I'm looking for an answer that is independent of the number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by only `a` column from `df1` and for replace missing values is added forward filling them:

```
df = df1[['a']].merge(df2, how='left', on='a').ffill()
print (df)
   a    b
0  1  2.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  4.0
3  4  5.0
4  5  5.0
```

Or use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1[['a']], df2, on='a')
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  2
2  3  4
3  4  5
4  5  5
```